# javascript module in with nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, webserver, nginx-config

I'm setting a webserver on my local machine using nginx, but I'm not able to run javascript. When I try to import a javascript file as a module, I run into "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec". My nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 1;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
      location / {
        root /home/jyoung/Web/Test1/www;
      }     
      location /images/ {
        root /home/jyoung/Web/Test1;
      }
    }
}

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    use epoll;
}
```

I have restarted nginx every time I've made edits. I'd be grateful for any tips.